# Try to build old project but getting error of animationDuration

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

Facing issue on while build the project add code

304:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'animationDuration'.
animationDuration: dataRaised?.animationDuration,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart:65:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const ElevatedButton({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.9.5/lib/src/platform_button.dart:266:14: Error: A value of type 'ElevatedButton' can't be returned from a function with return type 'MaterialButton'.

- 'ElevatedButton' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/elevated_button.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/elevated_button.dart').
- 'MaterialButton' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/material_button.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material_button.dart').
  return ElevatedButton(
  ^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.9.5/lib/src/platform_dialog_action.dart:170:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'color'.
  color: data?.color,
  ^^^^^
  /C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_button.dart:77:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const TextButton({
  ^^^^^^^^^^
  ../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not found: 'packageRoot'.
  io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  ^^^^^^^^^^^

try to help the run the project

Comment: hi, did you change your button from 'RaisedButton' to 'ElevatedButton'.. also can you please provide the code of your ElevatedButton.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_platform_widgets-1.20.0/lib/src/platform_button.dart:268:10: Error: A value must be explicitly returned from a non-void function.
         return ;

Comment: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'MaterialButton' doesn't allow null.
 - 'MaterialButton' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/material_button.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/material_button.dart').
  MaterialButton createMaterialWidget(BuildContext context) {